# When I install the "Smarty", php, you need to lock the folders templates and templates_r for public access?

Tags: php, templates, smarty

Using the .htaccess to deny for example.
Because otherwise , part of the "php code" would be exposed to users who enter the files by URL.

Comment: and the question is....

Comment: o.o, If it is important to block these folders

Comment: those templates viewed without going through the smarty parser are going to give the user an unprecedented view of the inner workings of your app, possibly exposing an attack vector for some evil genius.

Comment: Thank you. Then your recommendation is actually using. htaccess?

Comment: If possible the best solution would be to get it outside of the document root if possible... .htaccess would be a viable second choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should block any and all files that do not NEED to be publicly accessible, including Smarty compiled templates. Even if something seems like it's not a big deal, you just don't know, and there's no reason to NOT block it.

You can either have these files outside of your document root - easy to do with Smarty, just point its compile dir elsewhere - or you can use htaccess (or the equivalent for your server) to block this folder or some parent folder containing this folder.

In my own code, to keep things portable and to simplify deployment, I keep everything within the document root. However, all of my code, including Smarty compiled templates, is contained within a single sub-folder which I have configured nginx to block from public access, giving me blanket security.